# CoreData check if to-many-relationship contains object

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many

I have the following data model in my app:

[image: data model]

Basically I want to store country names aswell as city names. Each city belongs to one country and one country contains 0 - n cities.

Before I now add new cities to a certain country I need to know if the country already contains a city with this name.

Until now I do this:

```
- (BOOL)countryForName:(NSString *)countryName containsCity:(NSString *)cityName {
    Countries *country = [self countryForName:countryName];
    NSSet *cityNames = [country valueForKey:@"cities"];
    for (Cities *city in cityNames) {
        if ([city.cityName isEqualToString:cityName]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This obviously is very slow, what I need is an equivalent fetch with a correct predicate. I perform a search for one entity like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity     = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Countries" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor    = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"countryName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors            = @[sortDescriptor];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors        = sortDescriptors;

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"GetCountryList"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate  = self;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countryName == %@", countryName];
[aFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

But how do I do this if a search involves multiple entities? Or in other words:  How do I add unique city names for one country only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to check that a given country object already contains a city with a name,
you can do

```c
Countries *country = ...
NSString *cityName = ...
if ([[country valueForKeyPath:@"cities.name"] containsObject:cityName]) {
    // ...
}
```

Or, using a fetch request:

```c
NSString *countryName = ...
NSString *cityName = ...
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Countries"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countryName == %@ AND ANY cities.cityName == %@", countryName, cityName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (count == NSNotFound) {
    // error
} else if (count == 0) {
    // no matching country
} else {
    // at least one matching country
}
```

Note that a `NSFetchedResultsController` is normally used to display the contents of a 
fetch request in a table view, so it is not needed here.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank your for this reply. This solution only looks like a very little improvement to my code. Is there no way to create a fetchrequest and then perform `countForFetchRequest:` returning 0 for "country does not contain this city" or a value > 0 for "country contains this city"? I do not really like to create objects in order to reduce memory usage...

Comment: I just tested your code, it works perfectly now. I edited your answers code so others can take advantage of it, thank you very much :)

Comment: @pmk: You are welcome (and yes, there were some stupid errors in the code). - I have just re-inserted the convenience method `fetchRequestWithEntityName` (now hopefully correctly), that saves 2 lines of code.

Comment: Let's say you have an array cityNames ['CityA', 'CityB', 'CityC']. How would you fetch countries that contain all of the cities or one of the cities in the array?